# What are these extra characters in my byte strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth

I have a Python 3 script that gets data from some Bluetooth LE sensors. The data I'm getting is in 20-byte strings, but it looks like there are some extra characters along with the typical `\x00` bytes. What are these extra characters? Why are they in seemingly random spots in the string?

Here is a chunk of byte strings that I am getting from the sensors.

```
b'\x96\x80G\x92\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f'
b'\xb1\xc1G\x92\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f'
b'\xcc\x02H\x92\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f'
b'\xe7CH\x92\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f'
b'\x02\x85H\x92\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f'
b'\x1d\xc6H\x92\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f'
b'8\x07I\x92\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f'
b'SHI\x92\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f'
b'n\x89I\x92\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f\x00\x00\xc0\x7f'
```

For example, the first line has a chunk that says `\x80G`. The second to last line starts with `SHI`. What does this mean?

Thank you.

Comment: This is the binary data that you requested. You must read the sensor documentation to understand what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the other answer, the `SHI` is just an artifact of the binary values being printed to the screen.

A couple of options for printing the values so this doesn't happen are:

```py
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sensor_data = b'\x53\x48\x49\x92\x00'
>>> sensor_data
b'SHI\x92\x00'
>>> list(sensor_data)
[83, 72, 73, 146, 0]
>>> [hex(x) for x in sensor_data]
['0x53', '0x48', '0x49', '0x92', '0x0']
>>> [f'{x:02x}' for x in sensor_data]
['53', '48', '49', '92', '00']
```

From Python 3.5 there is the `hex()` method on `bytes` to output a string object of hexadecimal digits. e.g.

```py
>>> sensor_data.hex()
'5348499200'
>>> sensor_data.hex(' ')
'53 48 49 92 00'
```

Comment: Note to OP and future visitors: this is just representation of the binary data. At the end of the day, you are probably more interested in interpreting the data, so the representation only matters as far as human understanding while you write code to do something with it. The representation doesn't matter to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

If the byte data is an ASCII character, then that character will be shown instead of the `\xXX` escape code. So for example `b'G'` is the same as `b'\x47'`, `b'S'` is  the same as `b'\x53'`, etc.

As for what this value actually means, I can't tell you. I'm not familiar with the protocols you are using here.