# BLE sniffing: btsnoop log from adb bugreport using python script - encoding/decoding problems

Tags: python, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to reading Bluetooth device (BLE) data, and tried to follow [this Medium tutorial](https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/how-i-hacked-xiaomi-miband-2-to-control-it-from-linux-a5bd2f36d3ad) (my Bluetooth Device is an Amazfit Bip).

I got stuck with finding the btsnoop_hci.log file (from a Samsung Galaxy S7), so I ran `adb bugreport anewbugreportfolder` as [recommended in this Stack Overflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30352487/6465789).
In order for reproducibility, I uploaded the relevant part of my bugreport to [Dropbox here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ppjxgyfzokpdss/bugreport-part.txt?dl=0).

**My issue is:** when I try to run `btsnoop.py` [(can be found here)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/master/tools/scripts/btsnooz.py) as recommended in the Stack Overflow answer linked above, I get very strange output that can't possibly be intended (for example, it starts with `��^D#}` and contains lots of those weird question mark characters).

Is there some parts of the Python script that need to be adjusted for it to work correctly, for example encodings (none of the standard ones seem to give better results)? I am using Python 3.7. Alternatively, might it be about my Bluetooth device?

Comment: Is this just an issue with binary values trying to be printed to the screen? Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64347348/7721752 ? With the question marks being unprintable ASCII values

Comment: This was the issue. I have no Wireshark experience, so I expected a reabable log-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the output of the tool. It's your expectation of what to expect, that's incorrect: The output of the tool is binary content, not a text file.

The following command (not that the tool is called btsnooz, not btsnoop) redirects the binary output to a new file called `btsnoop_hci.log`:

```
$ python2 ./btsnooz.py ./bugreport-part.txt > btsnoop_hci.log

$ file btsnoop_hci.log
btsnoop_hci.log: BTSnoop version 1, HCI UART (H4)
```

The software Wireshark is perfectly able to interpret the produced BTSnoop logfile:

```
wireshark btsnoop_hci.log
```

[image: Screenshot of Wireshark interpreting the file btsnoop_hci.log]

A good filter to see only the relevant packets with CID 0x0004 is `btl2cap.cid == 0x0004`:

[image]

More hints on how to proceed can be found in this tutorial: [Reverse Engineering BLE Devices - Application Protocol Reverse Engineering](https://reverse-engineering-ble-devices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol_reveng/00_protocol_reveng.html)

Comment: This solves my issue, thank you. I only got btsnooz.py to run using Python2. There is some error though (btsnoop: File has 771751936-byte packet, bigger than maximum of 262144), which is probably because of specifics in my bugreport.

Comment: Glad, I was able to help. Yes, btsnooz.py is for Python2 as of the [current version 082c2af](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/082c2af3e594200ffbf3232657afde586ad20ba7/tools/scripts/btsnooz.py). Besides, the error message you get - does it come from your call of btsnooz.py? I don't get such a message, when running it against the file you provided in your question ("bugreport-part.txt"). Do you call it on the file from a different `adb bugreport` run?