# How do I represent longer bytes in Python?

Tags: python, hex, byte

The most significant bits are removed when converting to hex. What's the best way to represent arbitrarily long hex values and treat them as bytes?

```
(Pdb) hex(0x641BEAC6)
'0x641beac6'
(Pdb) 0x641BEAC6.to_bytes(4, 'big')
b'd\x1b\xea\xc6'
```

Here we see the most significant bits 0x64 isn't there.

Same thing here:

```
(Pdb) bytes.fromhex("641BEAC6")
b'd\x1b\xea\xc6'

(Pdb) data = 1679551174 #int representation of 0x641BEAC6
(Pdb) data.to_bytes(4, 'big')
b'd\x1b\xea\xc6'
```

Why isn't the most significant bits 0x64 being converted to bytes?

Comment: `0x64` _is_ being converted to a byte in both cases – `chr(0x64)` is lowercase `d`, which you can see at the start of the strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are these extra characters in my byte strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343864/what-are-these-extra-characters-in-my-byte-strings)

Comment: This answers my question! For folks that want to keep printing them as bytes in hex instead of converting the bytes to ascii whenever it falls into ascii range, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690025/print-bytes-to-hex)